# Unable to use Form with class component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, antd

I'm using **Antd Form** using `class components` with `typescript`. I'm accessing **[FormInstance](https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance)** methods using `createRef()` explained in this [example](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-control-ref), unfortunately after banging my head and spending a lot of time it didn't work at all. Below are the code and error which I'm getting any kind of help would be much appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Form
} from "antd";
import FormInstance from "antd/lib/form";

class PriceTable extends React.Component<
  IPriceProps,
  any
> {
  formRef: React.RefObject<Form>;
this.formRef = React.createRef<FormInstance>();
}

 edit = (record: any) => {
    this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue({
      name: "",
      age: "",
      address: "",
      ...record,
    });
    this.setState({ setEditingKey: record.key });
  };
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

wrong types

```
formRef: React.RefObject<FormInstance>; // setFieldsValue does not exist on form but on FormInstance
this.formRef = React.createRef<FormInstance>();
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this option also but it didn't work, was given the same error

Comment: weird,.. share ansver when u figure it out